# Using Swift Argo framework : Could not find an overload for '<*>'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Argo with Runes and Box framework , i have followed the Carthage way of adding frameworks.
Here is my Model Class for Cities

```
import Argo
import Runes

struct Cities {

let cityName: String
let cityState: String

 }

extension Cities: Decodable {
static func create(cityName: String)(cityState: String!) -> Cities {
    return Cities(cityName: cityName, cityState: cityState)
}

static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<Cities>
{
    return Cities.create <*> j <| "cityName" <*> j <| "cityState"

}
}
```

I get the following error : Could not find an overload for '<*>' that accepts the supplied arguments
at return Cities.create <*> j <| "cityName" <*> j <| "cityState"

How can i fix this issue?

sample json :

```
{"cityName":"Panaji","cityState":"Goa"}
```

Xcode: **v6.4**

Answer (score 0):

> After Cities.create you must put <^> operator

Here is your modified code:

```
import Argo
import Runes

struct Cities {

let cityName: String
let cityState: String

 }

extension Cities: Decodable {
static func create(cityName: String)(cityState: String!) -> Cities {
    return Cities(cityName: cityName, cityState: cityState)
}

static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<Cities>
{

    return Cities.create <^> j <| "cityName" // modified line
                         <*> j <| "cityState"

}
}
```

In the last version of Argo you could do like that:

```
    import Argo
    import Curry

    struct Cities {
       let cityName: String
       let cityState: String
    }
    extension Cities: Decodable {
       static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<Cities> {
          return curry(Cities.init) 
              <^> j <| "cityName"
              <*> j <| "cityState"
       }
    }
```